# What are the exact percentages for likelihood of getting 3 diamonds from a diamond ore with Fortune 3?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a modification that adds a furnace that doubles the amount of ingots produced from an ore when smelted. I want to know if using this furnace to smelt diamond ore would be better than using a fortune 3 diamond pickaxe. So what is the likelihood of getting three (or more maybe) diamonds from an ore with a fortune 3 pickaxe so I can determine if the furnace is better to use because it gives a guaranteed two diamonds. Thanks!

Comment: Mining with the pick should produce more diamonds, since it is from 2-3 diamonds per an ore (if I remember correctly). Also, if you plan on using the furnace, make sure to mine the ore with a pickaxe with silk touch on it, or else you will only get only diamonds, no ore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Fortune):

> Fortune increases block drops.
> For coal, diamond, emerald, nether quartz, and lapis lazuli, level I gives a 33% chance to multiply drops by 2 (averaging 33% increase), level II gives a chance to multiply drops by 2 or 3 (25% chance each, averaging 75% increase), and level III gives a chance to multiply drops by 2, 3, or 4 (20% chance each, averaging 120% increase).

Sounds like the fortune pickaxe is the way to go.

Comment: I have read the wiki, but is a 40% chance of still getting one and a 40% chance of getting more than three better than a 100% chance of getting two?

Comment: Fortune III averages 120% increase.  Furnace is only 100% increase plus requires mining with silk touch and consumes fuel.  I would go with the fortune pickaxe.

Comment: It's funny, it turns out that I was wrong and smelting diamond ore with this furnace actually doesn't duplicate it! It only works for iron ore and other ores included in the mod.